# Edit & Continue fails most of the time

Tags: c++, visual-studio

What is the cause, that I receive this error most of the time:

Edit & Continue: error : "Recompilation of "xxx" was interrupted by a debug operation. Please try again"
Edit & Continue: An error occured while applying code changes.

It's weird, as it works sometimes, but if it starts failing, it's consistent.

Comment: This is something that fails less often than I would expect, but when you change a program out from under the debugger, the smallest difference could make what is currently in memory inconsistent with the revised program.

Comment: There are no magic. If nature of your changes does not let it to continue then it does not. Try to write more before debug sessions and to check it with unit tests; debug sessions will be never correct tool of implementing features in "as we go" manner.

Comment: Even if I make absolutley no changes to the code, i.e. when I add/remove a space character, I get this error.. So there is some magic going on..

Comment: Honestly, do you find edit and continue useful? I just turn it off.

Comment: Honestly, I definitively need it for the development of DLLs for a 3D application! Each relaunch takes about 30..60 seconds (thanks to MS DLL hell). Sometimes the re-compilations takes also >60 seconds (on a high end development machine) - but if Edit&Continue works, it saves a lot of time!

Comment: What is your Visual Studio version? Are there steps to reproduce your problem?

Comment: VS2019. 
If there would be reproduceable steps, I would simply omit them. 
Even rebuilding sometimes does not help. It looks like it depends where I put breakpoints and which files on which location I'm changing. Sometimes I have to extract some code to new source files, just to make edit&continue working again.

Comment: What about the latest Visual Studio 2022?  There have been many edit and continue error [reports](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/cpp?q=edit+and+continue+error) of VS2019.

Comment: Good idea, but as I have to stick to a certain complier version, I'm sure it will not help just changing the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

Considering 3D applications, the problem you are facing may be related to the conflict between the modern libraries and the hot reload.  You could vote for [the request](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Greatly-enhancing-CC-edit-and-continu/1247395?q=edit%20and%20continue%20error) to promote feature improvements.

Comment: Recode looks promising - but do they still exist? No response from them so far..